# How to rename files keeping a variable part of the original file name

Tags: shell

I'm trying to make a script that will go into a directory and run my own application with each file matching a regular expression, specifically `Test[0-9]*.txt`.

My input filenames look like this `TestXX.txt`. Now, I could just use cut and chop off the `Test` and `.txt`, but how would I do this if `XX` wasn't predefined to be two digits? What would I do if I had `Test1.txt`, ..., `Test10.txt`? In other words, How would I get the `[0-9]*` part?

Just so you know, I want to be able to make a `OutputXX.txt` :)

EDIT:

I have files with filename `Test[0-9]*.txt` and I want to manipulate the string into `Output[0-9]*.txt`

Comment: @Buttink, the question does not seem to convey the meaning properly, can you edit it ?

Comment: @Kalu I edited a "keep it simple" sort of questions will make it easyer to understand XP

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this help?

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in Test*.txt ;
do
    process < $f > ${f/Test/Output}
done
```

[Bash Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: This worked! Im stupid and am still trying to figure out how to make my process run but thats another matter.

Comment: @keith, this worked but it works for all cases, not just numbers.. do you intend to process `TestABC.txt` as well?

Comment: +1. Don't forget to quote: `process <"$f" >"${f/Test/Output}"`. This parameter expansion would work too: `"Output${f#Test}"`

Answer (score 2):

A good tutorial on regexes in bash is [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions).  Summarizing, you need something like:

```
if [[$filenamein =~ "^Test([0-9]*).txt$"]]; then
  filenameout = "Output${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt"
```

and so on.  The key is that, when you perform the `=~" regex-match, the "sub-matches" to parentheses-enclosed groups in the RE are set in the entries of array`BASH_REMATCH`(the`[0]`entry is the whole match,`[1](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions)` the first parentheses-enclosed group, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use rounded brackets around the part you want to keep.

i.e. "Test([0-9]*).txt"

The syntax for replacing these bracketed groups varies between programs, but you'll probably find you can use \1 , something like this:

s/Test(0-9*).txt/Output\1.txt/

If you're using a unix shell, then 'sed' might be your best bet for performing the transformation.

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4

Hope that helps

Comment: Looks sweet to bad I can't set two answers. One is simple and the other more extendable >.> gay

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in Test[0-9]*.txt;
do
 num=${file//[^0-9]/}
 process $file > "Output${num}.txt"
done
```