# Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

a lot of files I download have crap/spam in their filenames, e.g.

`[ www.crap.com ] file.name.ext`

`www.crap.com - file.name.ext`

I've come up with two ways for dealing with them but they both seem pretty clunky:

with parameter expansion:

```
if [[ ${base_name} != ${base_name//\[+([^\]])\]} ]]
then
    mv -v "${dir_name}/${base_name}" "${dir_name}/${base_name//\[+([^\]])\]}" &&
        base_name="${base_name//\[+([^\]])\]}"
fi

if [[ ${base_name} != ${base_name//www.*.com - /} ]]
then
    mv -v "${dir_name}/${base_name}" "${dir_name}/${base_name//www.*.com - /}" &&
        base_name="${base_name//www.*.com - /}"
fi

# more of these type of statements; one for each type of frequently-encountered pattern
```

and then with echo/sed:

```
tmp=`echo "${base_name}" | sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' | sed -e 's/\s-\s//g'`
mv "${base_name}" "{tmp}"
```

I feel like the parameter expansion is the worse of the two but I like it because I'm able to keep the same variable assigned to the file for further processing after the rename (the above code is used in a script that's called for each file after the file download is complete).

So anyway I was hoping there's a better/cleaner way to do the above that someone more knowledgeable than myself could show me, preferably in a way that would allow me to easily reassign the old/original variable to the new/renamed file.

Thanks

Comment: create a temporary file with a ls, change it with a sed and apply result (ex: mv "/Path/www.crap.com - file.name.ext" "/Path/file.name.ext")

Comment: Please post a part of `ls` output as sample (~10lines).

Comment: does the `file.name.ext` part have spaces?

Comment: if not, then use `if [[ "${file_name}" =~ '(|.*/)[^/]*([^ /]+)$' ]]; then mv "${file_name}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; fi`

Answer (score 13):

### Two answer: using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) rename or using *pure* [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

As there are some people who dislike perl, I wrote *my* bash only version

### Renaming files by using the `rename` command.

#### Introduction

Yes, this is a typical job for `rename` command which was precisely designed for:

```
man rename | sed -ne '/example/,/^[^ ]/p'
   For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the
   extension, you might say

           rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak

   To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use

           rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

#### More oriented samples

Simply drop all *spaces* and *square brackets*:

```
rename 's/[ \[\]]*//g;' *.ext
```

Rename all `.jpg` by numbering from `1`:

```
rename 's/^.*$/sprintf "IMG_%05d.JPG",++$./e' *.jpg
```

Demo:

```
touch {a..e}.jpg
ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 e.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 d.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 c.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 b.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 a.jpg
rename 's/^.*$/sprintf "IMG_%05d.JPG",++$./e' *.jpg
ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 IMG_00005.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 IMG_00004.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 IMG_00003.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 IMG_00002.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 sep  6 16:35 IMG_00001.JPG
```

#### Full syntax for matching SO question, in safe way

There is a *strong and safe* way using `rename` utility:

As this is [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) common tool, we have to use perl syntax:

```
rename 'my $o=$_;
        s/[ \[\]]+/-/g;
        s/-+/-/g;
        s/^-//g;
        s/-\(\..*\|\)$/$1/g;
        s/(.*[^\d])(|-(\d+))(\.[a-z0-9]{2,6})$/
                my $i=$3;
                $i=0 unless $i;
                sprintf("%s-%d%s", $1, $i+1, $4)
            /eg while
               $o ne $_  &&
               -f $_;
    ' *
```

Testing rule:

```
touch '[ www.crap.com ] file.name.ext' 'www.crap.com - file.name.ext'
ls -1
[ www.crap.com ] file.name.ext
www.crap.com - file.name.ext
rename 'my $o=$_; ...
    ...
    ...' *
ls -1
www.crap.com-file.name-1.ext
www.crap.com-file.name.ext

touch '[ www.crap.com ] file.name.ext' 'www.crap.com - file.name.ext'
ls -1
www.crap.com-file.name-1.ext
[ www.crap.com ] file.name.ext
www.crap.com - file.name.ext
www.crap.com-file.name.ext
rename 'my $o=$_; ...
    ...
    ...' *
ls -1
www.crap.com-file.name-1.ext
www.crap.com-file.name-2.ext
www.crap.com-file.name-3.ext
www.crap.com-file.name.ext
```

... and so on...

... and it's safe while you don't use `-f` flag to `rename` command: file won't be overwrited and you will get an error message if something goes wrong.

### Renaming files by using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and so called *bashisms*:

I prefer doing this by using dedicated utility, but this could even be done by using **pure** [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (aka without any fork)

There is no use of any other binary than bash (no `sed`, `awk`, `tr` or other):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file;do
    newname=${file//[ \]\[]/.}
    while [ "$newname" != "${newname#.}" ] ;do
        newname=${newname#.}
      done
    while [ "$newname" != "${newname//[.-][.-]/.}" ] ;do
        newname=${newname//[.-][.-]/-};done
    if [ "$file" != "$newname" ] ;then
        if [ -f $newname ] ;then
            ext=${newname##*.}
            basename=${newname%.$ext}
            partname=${basename%%-[0-9]}
            count=${basename#${partname}-}
            [ "$partname" = "$count" ] && count=0
            while printf -v newname "%s-%d.%s" $partname $[++count] $ext &&
                  [ -f "$newname" ] ;do
              :;done
          fi
        mv  "$file" $newname
      fi
  done
```

To be run with files as argument, for sample:

```
/path/to/my/script.sh \[*
```

- Replacing spaces and square bracket by dot
- Replacing sequences of `.-`, `-.`, `--` or `..` by only one `-`.
- Test if filename don't differ, there is nothing to do.
- Test if a file exist with *newname*...
- split filename, counter and extension, for making indexed *newname*
- loop if a file exist with *newname*
- Finaly rename the file.

Answer (score 7):

Take advantage of the following classical pattern:

```
 job_select /path/to/directory| job_strategy | job_process
```

where `job_select` is responsible for selecting the objects of your job, `job_strategy` prepares a processing plan for these objects and `job_process` eventually executes the plan.

*This assumes that filenames do not contain a vertical bar `|` nor a newline character.*

**The job_select function**

```
 # job_select PATH
 #  Produce the list of files to process
 job_select()
 {
   find "$1" -name 'www.*.com - *' -o -name '[*] - *'
 }
```

The `find` command can examine all properties of the file maintained by the file system, like creation time, access time, modification time.  It is also possible to control how the filesystem is explored by telling `find` not to descend into mounted filesystems, how much recursions levels are allowed.  It is common to append pipes to the `find` command to perform more complicated selections based on the filename.

*Avoid the common pitfall* of including the contents of hidden directories in the output of the `job_select` function.  For instance, the directories `CVS`, `.svn`, `.svk` and `.git` are used by the corresponding source control management tools and it is almost always wrong to include their contents in the output of the `job_select` function.  By inadvertently batch processing these files, one can easily make the affected working copy unusable.

**The job_strategy function**

```
# job_strategy
#  Prepare a plan for renaming files
job_strategy()
{
  sed -e '
    h
    s@/www\..*\.com - *@/@
    s@/\[^]]* - *@/@
    x
    G
    s/\n/|/
  '
}
```

This commands reads the output of `job_select` and makes a plan for our renaming job. The plan is represented by text lines having two fields separated by the character `|`, the first field being the old name of the file and the second being the new computed file of the file, it looks like

```
[ www.crap.com ] file.name.1.ext|file.name.1.ext
www.crap.com - file.name.2.ext|file.name.2.ext
```

The particular program used to produce the plan is essentially irrelevant, but it is common to use `sed` as in the example; `awk` or `perl` for this.  Let us walk through the `sed`-script used here:

```
h       Replace the contents of the hold space with the contents of the pattern space.
…       Edit the contents of the pattern space.
x       Swap the contents of the pattern and hold spaces.
G       Append a newline character followed by the contents of the hold space to the pattern space.
s/\n/|/ Replace the newline character in the pattern space by a vertical bar.
```

It can be easier to use several filters to prepare the plan.  Another common case is the use of the `stat` command to add creation times to file names.

**The job_process function**

```
# job_process
#  Rename files according to a plan
job_process()
{
   local oldname
   local newname
   while IFS='|' read oldname newname; do
     mv "$oldname" "$newname"
   done
}
```

The *input field separator* IFS is adjusted to let the function read the output of `job_strategy`.  Declaring `oldname` and `newname` as local is useful in large programs but can be omitted in very simple scripts.  The `job_process` function can be adjusted to avoid overwriting existing files and report the problematic items.

**About data structures in shell programs**
Note the use of pipes to transfer data from one stage to the other: apprentices often rely on variables to represent such information but it turns out to be a clumsy choice. Instead, it is preferable to represent data as tabular files or as tabular data streams moving from one process to the other, in this form, data can be easily processed by powerful tools like `sed`, `awk`, `join`, `paste` and `sort` — only to cite the most common ones.

Comment: Your job_strategy does not consider path names.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 What do you actually mean? The `job_strategy` is a filter reading path names and writing a renaming plan.

Comment: This `s/^www\..*\.com - *//` will not work on `foo/www.bar.com` because of the `^`. And the `find` will always output a path name, possibly `./`

Comment: If only `read` needs the new value for `IFS` then `while IFS='|' read oldname newname; do` is likely better than changing `IFS` like that. As your scripts runs `mv` with the modified value for `IFS`.

Comment: This also likely isn't safe for filenames with embedded newlines. For that you'd need to use `\0` as the separator and be a little more clever with your selection and processing steps.

Comment: @EtanReisner Your comment about IFS is excellent!  I also add a note to  emphasize that I am not interested by file names containing `|` or newlines.

Comment: I typically join `job_strategy` and `job_process` into a script because passing data compounds in text is unreliable unless sanitation is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm)

```
rnm -rs '/\[crap\]|\[spam\]//g' *.ext
```

The above will remove `[crap]` or `[spam]` from filename.

You can pass multiple regex pattern by terminating them with `;` or overloading the `-rs` option.

```
rnm -rs '/[\[\]]//g;/\s*\[crap\]//g' -rs '/crap2//' *.ext
```

The general format of this replace string is `/search_part/replace_part/modifier`

1. *search_part* : regex to search for.
2. *replace_part* : string to replace with
3. *modifier* : i (case insensitive), g (global replace)

**uppercase/lowercase:**

A replace string of the form `/search_part/\c/modifier` will make the selected part of the filename (by the regex `search_part`) lowercase while `\C` (capital \C) in replace part will make it uppercase.

```
rnm -rs '/[abcd]/\C/g' *.ext
## this will capitalize all a,b,c,d in the filenames
```

---

If you have many regex patterns that need to be dealt with, then put those patterns in a file and pass the file with `-rs/f` option.

```
rnm -rs/f /path/to/regex/pattern/file *.ext
```

You can find some other examples [here](https://neurobin.org/docs/unix/rnm).

**Note:**

1. rnm uses PCRE2 (revised PCRE) regex.
2. You can undo an unwanted rename operation by running `rnm -u`

P.S: I am the author of this tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubunntu/Debian os use rename command to rename multiple files at time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something not depending on perl, you can use the following code (let's call it `sanitizeNames.sh`). It is only showing a few cases, but it's easily extensible using string substitution, tr (and sed too).

```
    #!/bin/bash

    ls $1 |while read f; do
      newfname=$(echo "$f" \
                  |tr -d '\[ ' \    # Removing opened square bracket
                  |tr ' \]' '-' \   # Translating closing square bracket to dash
                  |tr -s '-' \      # Squeezing multiple dashes
                  |tr -s '.' \      # Squeezing multiple dots
                )
      newfname=${newfname//-./.}

      if [ -f "$newfname" ]; then
        # Some string magic...
        extension=${newfname##*\.}
        basename=${newfname%\.*}
        basename=${basename%\-[1-9]*}
        lastNum=$[ $(ls $basename*|wc -l) ] 
        mv "$f" "$basename-$lastNum.$extension"
      else
        mv "$f" "$newfname"
      fi
    done
```

And use it:

```
    $ touch '[ www.crap.com ] file.name.ext' 'www.crap.com - file.name.ext' '[ www.crap.com ] - file.name.ext' '[www.crap.com ].file.anothername.ext2' '[www.crap.com ].file.name.ext'
    $ ls -1 *crap*
    [ www.crap.com ] - file.name.ext
    [ www.crap.com ] file.name.ext
    [www.crap.com ].file.anothername.ext2
    [www.crap.com ].file.name.ext
    www.crap.com - file.name.ext
    $ ./sanitizeNames.sh *crap*
    $ ls -1 *crap*
    www.crap.com-file.anothername.ext2
    www.crap.com-file.name-1.ext
    www.crap.com-file.name-2.ext
    www.crap.com-file.name-3.ext
    www.crap.com-file.name.ext
```