# Batch rename directories to match name of a file in subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, directory, directory-structure, batch-rename

I have many directories within `/home/environment` named with various time and date stamps.  I want to rename all of these directories so that instead of a time date stamp each directory has the name of the `.txt` file it contains as part of a shell script.  *E.g.*

**Before**

```
/home/environment/2014-03-12-09-49-26/xxxx-A.2A1-xxxx-0x_B.txt
/home/environment/2014-03-12-09-50-34/xxxx-C.D57-xxxx-4x_E.txt
```

**After**

```
/home/environment/xxxx-A.2A1-xxxx-0x_B/xxxx-A.2A1-xxxx-0x_B.txt
/home/environment/xxxx-C.D57-xxxx-4x_E/xxxx-C.D57-xxxx-4x_E.txt
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer `/home/environment/xxxx-A.2A1-xxxx-0x_B/xxxx-A.2A1-xxxx-0x_B.txt` over `/home/environment/xxxx-A.2A1-xxxx-0x_B.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to the question [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678) describes a general pattern you can us here:

```
 job_select /path/to/directory| job_strategy | job_process
```

where `job_select` is responsible for selecting the objects of your job, `job_strategy` prepares a processing plan for these objects and `job_process` eventually executes the plan. For a general discussion about this pattern, please see the previous question, I will only write down an implementation here.

*This assumes that filenames do not contain a vertical bar `|` nor a newline character.*

**The job_select function**

```
 # job_select PATH
 #  Produce the list of files to process
 job_select()
 {
   find "$1" -type f -name '*.txt'
 }
```

**The job_strategy function**

```
# job_strategy
#  Prepare a plan for renaming directories
job_strategy()
{
  sed -e 's@/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)\.txt$@|\1|\2@'
}
```

**The job_process function**

```
# job_process
#  Rename directories according to a plan
job_process()
{
   local radical oldname newname
   while IFS='|' read radical oldname newname; do
     mv "$radical/$oldname" "$radical/$newname"
   done
}
```

Note that this assumes that files in distinct directories are distinct.