# How do I rename all files in a folder with a shellscript?

Tags: shell

I recently got some music mp3 on my laptop, but they're all name "songtitle.mp3.mp3"

anybody know how to remove the second .mp3 on all files? thanks in advance

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `awk` and pipe the result into the shell:

```
ls | awk -F. '{print "mv "$0" "$1"."$3}' | sh
```

**hint:**
this solution will only work, if you have no `.` in the filename (in your case in the songtitle) else.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a programming related Q&A site, simply using mmv is out of question ;-)

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.mp3.mp3; do
    j=`basename "$i" .mp3`
    mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

If the question was mistakenly asked on SO, here is the man page:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/mmv.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%` form of parameter expansion.

```
for f in *.mp3.mp3; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.mp3}"
done
```

You can find the documentation for this in the Parameter Expansion section of the `bash` man page.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` solutions such as the one from chepner should do the trick.

I'd like to mention the possibility to use `sed` here, with the `e` command that executes the result of a substitution (use with caution: first try without the `e` command at the end of the line to print what would be executed).

That would make:

```
ls -1 *.mp3.mp3 | sed 's/\(.+\.mp3\)\.mp3$/mv & \1/e'
```

It should list all files in current directory ending with `.mp3.mp3`, for example: `toto.mp3.mp3`. String `toto.mp3.mp3` is piped to sed, which substitues `mv toto.mp3.mp3 toto.mp3` instead, prints it and executes it.