# compare and rename only files in a directory using regexp based on a original folder

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, diff

I need to rename only files in sub-directories of a folder based on another folder (original folder) and its sub-directories ...

Folder1 contain the correct files name so if a file  in some sub-directory  under folder2 and exist in same location as folder1 (original) will be renamed as original file.

Example :

```
.
├── folder1
│   ├── Somedir
│   │   ├── file.xml
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   │   ├── CHANGELOG
│   │   │   ├── TEST
│   │   │   ├── file_test.txt
│   │   │   ├── sample
│   │   │   ├── README
│   │   │   ├── mydir
│   │   │   │   ├── exploitation-file.rst
│   │   │   │   ├── advanced-file.txt


.
├── folder2
│   ├── Somedir
│   │   ├── file.xml
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   │   ├── CHANGELOG
│   │   │   ├── TEST
│   │   │   ├── filetest.txt
│   │   │   ├── sample
│   │   │   ├── README
│   │   │   ├── mydir
│   │   │   │   ├── exploitationfile.rst
│   │   │   │   ├── advancedfile.txt
```

after running "diff -qr /folder1 /folder2" I got the differences between these two folders is this case are :

```
/folder2/somedir/filetest.txt (missing underscore)  vs /folder1/somedir/file_test.txt 

/folder2/somedir/doc/mydir/exploitation-file.rst (missing hyphen) vs /folder1/somedir/doc/mydir/exploitation-file.rst 

/folder2/somedir/doc/mydir/advanced-file.txt (missing hyphen) vs /folder1/somedir/doc/mydir/advanced-file.txt
```

Comment: this problem happens when I execute a script by error that  remove underscore and hyphen in every file name.

Comment: "folder1" is the original folder that is an old backup that I did a couples of weeks ago.

Comment: on which criteria a file should be renamed ? folder1/file_name.ext wher in folder2 there are filename.ext so if any file is the same as folder1 with `_` ? in this case what for folder1/fi_lename.ext or folder1/file_name.ext_ ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu yes ! if a file located in "folder2" named "FileName.ex"(not correct name) and the original file named "F_ile-Na_me.ex_"(correct name) in "folder1(original)" ,                             the file located in folder2 named "FileName.ex" (not correct) will be renamed to "F_ile-Na_me.ex_" (correct).

Comment: underscore and hyphen must used in regexp.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu only files not directories

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Any Idea !? note : I am using ubuntu linux !

Comment: @NeronLeVelu should I make something to deal with the output of "diff -qr /folder1 /folder2" !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a combination of [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) and [`Path::Class::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::Rule).

The most difficult part of creating a solution to a problem like this is testing it.  I therefore provide a completely self-contained script that creates a testing environment based off the example structure that you provided.

This script basically scans the `__DATA__` section for files and directories to create in a special testing directory.  Then the subsequent section of code actually fixes the `folder2` directory based off the information in `folder1`.

Note, this will require installation of the two above cpan modules and their dependencies.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Path::Class;
use Path::Class::Rule;

my $testdir = dir('testing');

# Setup Testing Environment
$testdir->rmtree();
$testdir->mkpath();
chdir($testdir);

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $type, $name ) = split;

    if ( $type eq 'd' ) {
        dir($name)->mkpath();
    } else {
        file($name)->spew($name);
    }
}

# Actual Solution
my $backup_dir = dir('folder1');
my $main_dir   = dir('folder2');

my $next = Path::Class::Rule->new->file->name(qr{[_-]})->iter($backup_dir);

while ( my $file = $next->() ) {
    my $correct_name = $file->basename();
    ( my $stripped_name = $correct_name ) =~ s{[_-]}{}g;

    my $from_file = file( $main_dir, $file->dir->relative($backup_dir), $stripped_name );
    my $to_file   = file( $main_dir, $file->dir->relative($backup_dir), $correct_name );

    if ( -e $from_file ) {
        print "$from_file -> $to_file\n";
        $from_file->move_to($to_file);
    }
}

__DATA__
d folder1
d folder1/Somedir
f folder1/Somedir/file.xml
d folder1/Somedir/doc
f folder1/Somedir/doc/CHANGELOG
f folder1/Somedir/doc/TEST
f folder1/Somedir/doc/file_test.txt
f folder1/Somedir/doc/sample
f folder1/Somedir/doc/README
d folder1/Somedir/doc/mydir
f folder1/Somedir/doc/mydir/exploitation-file.rst
f folder1/Somedir/doc/mydir/advanced-file.txt
d folder2
d folder2/Somedir
f folder2/Somedir/file.xml
d folder2/Somedir/doc
f folder2/Somedir/doc/CHANGELOG
f folder2/Somedir/doc/TEST
f folder2/Somedir/doc/filetest.txt
f folder2/Somedir/doc/sample
f folder2/Somedir/doc/README
d folder2/Somedir/doc/mydir
f folder2/Somedir/doc/mydir/exploitationfile.rst
f folder2/Somedir/doc/mydir/advancedfile.txt
```

Outputs:

```
folder2/Somedir/doc/filetest.txt -> folder2/Somedir/doc/file_test.txt
folder2/Somedir/doc/mydir/advancedfile.txt -> folder2/Somedir/doc/mydir/advanced-file.txt
folder2/Somedir/doc/mydir/exploitationfile.rst -> folder2/Somedir/doc/mydir/exploitation-file.rst
```

Comment: sounds great but how can I send "ls" output to the script without including files list (_DATA_) in the script ?

Comment: There is no need to include any info in the DATA block.  That is only used for testing purposes.  You simply use the section of code labeled with `Actual Solution` and setup your backup_dir and main_dir appropriately.

Comment: I recommend that you get this solution running as is.  Attempt to learn what it's doing.  And then it should be very clear how to adapt it to your real situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the general strategy detailed in [“Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678) which breaks down the renaming task in three stages:

```
job_select | job_strategy | job_process
```

where `job_select` is responsible for selecting the objects of your job, `job_strategy` prepares a processing plan for these objects and `job_process` eventually executes the plan.

```
# job_select SRCDIR
#  Find all files having a dash or a hyphen in name
job_select()
{
  (cd "$1" && find . -type f -name '*[-_]*')
}

# job_strategy
#  Compute the renaming plan
#
# This assume that wrong names are deduced from good names by removing `_` and `-`.
# The output has three columns,
#
#   reldir|goodname|badname
#
# For instance, ./somedir/file_test.txt yields the plan
#
#   ./somedir|file_test.txt|filestest.txt
job_strategy()
{
  sed -e '
    s@/\([^/]*\)$/@|\1@
    h
    s@^.*|@@
    s@[-_]@@g
    x
    G
    s/\n/|/
  '
}

# job_process TGTDIR
{
   cd "$1" || exit
   IFS='|'
   while read reldir goodname badname; do
     relgoodname="$reldir/$goodname"
     relbadname="$reldir/$badname"
     if [ -r "$relbadname" ]; then
       printf 'Rename %s to %s\n' "$relbadname" "$relgoodname"
       mv "$relbadname" "$relgoodname"
     else
       printf 'Skip %s\n' "$relbadname"
     fi
   done
}

job_select /folder1 | job_strategy | job_process /folder2
```

Comment: how should I call this script, some thing like this ?                    #./job_select.sh /folder1 | job_strategy | job_process /folder2

Comment: Paste the contents in a file `job_rename.sh` and call it as `sh job_rename.sh` — be sure to catch the last line, which is not displayed in my browser (I get a scrollbar)!  Before you run the script, be sure to have backups and comment out the `mv` command, this gives you the chance to review the action that would be undertaken and verify that it matches your expectations.

Comment: I got this output "Skip /badname" how can I set dir1 and dir2 ! if I run this script  will it fix all files names based on dir1 (original dir) ?

Comment: See arguments `/folder1` and `/folder2` on the bottom line. To your second question, yes, as it seems to be what defined the *right names* of files.

Comment: it returns nothing and I get "Skip /badname" when I press enter ! and nothing renamed ........           info : I am using ubuntu Linux

Comment: @saad I fixed a missing `$`.

Comment: now the output when I run the script and press Enter I get :           Rename / to /
mv: `/' and `/' are the same file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60636/discussion-between-michael-grunewald-and-saad).